# Оптимизация RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Реализовую `recyclerview` с `GridManager` для показа картинок из интернета. Для загрузки использую Picasso. Проблемма в том, что когда картинок очень много(>100) список, при быстром прокручивании тормозит, пытаясь сразу прорисовать картинки, даже если этого не требуется(например при прокручивании снизу вверх мне не нужно прорисовать весь список, а только там, где я остановлюсь). Слышал, это решается запретом загружать картинки во время скролинга. Кто знает ссылки на примеры такой реализации? или может какие то другие решения этой проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

На слабых устройствах было замечено:

Если у тебя больше 15 элементов сетка, все загружаемые проявляются fade-анимацией, если время загрузки очень маленькое или чтение идёт с диска и в этот момент происходит scroll - лаги возможны независимо от библиотеки.

Я углубленно занимался Image Loading для android - и экспериментировал как с собственным оптимизированным решением, так и с 3-rd part библиотеками.

Если вкратце - происходит следующее: когда в UI-поток слишком часто и быстро поступают готовые битмапы(н-р загрузка с диска + много ячеек сетка + быстрый скролл), каждый битмап - запускает fade анимацию - каждый drawable/imageView перерисовывается 30 раз/сек. И все они в разнобой заваливают UI поток событиями "invalidate drawable", "on Bitmap loaded"...

Следует не забывать, что ui-поток и так вынужден многое разгребать (жесты сенсора, скролл лист-вью, и мн.др) ... 
как правило это не проблема для большинства современных устройств

но маленькие слабые устройства не успевают одновременно и независимо анимировать много элементов на сцене, которая еще и сама при этом смещается. (силами Canvas-API)

Если с логикой загрузки у вас всё идеально - а скролл лагает - попробуйте уменьшить длительность фэйдов - либо вообще их отключить.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде такой штуки:

```
public class IdleRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private final IdleHandler mIdleHandler;
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private final Runnable mIdleRunnable = new Runnable() {

        int mRepeatCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mRecyclerView != null
                    && mIdleHandler != null
                    && mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null
                    && mRecyclerView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                mRepeatCount = 0;
                mIdleHandler.onIdle(
                        mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getPosition(mRecyclerView.getChildAt(0)),
                        mRecyclerView.getChildCount());
            } else if (mRecyclerView != null && ++mRepeatCount < 5) {
                mRecyclerView.postDelayed(mIdleRunnable, 200);
            }
        }
    };

    private int mLastState = -1;

    public IdleRecyclerViewScrollListener(IdleHandler idleHandler, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mIdleHandler = idleHandler;
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
            onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState != mLastState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                recyclerView.postDelayed(mIdleRunnable, 200);
            } else {
                recyclerView.removeCallbacks(mIdleRunnable);
            }
        }
        mLastState = newState;
    }

    public interface IdleHandler {

        void onIdle(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemsCount);

    }
}
```

И добавляем этот класс как листнер для recyclerview:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new IdleRecyclerViewScrollListener(
        new IdleRecyclerViewScrollListener.IdleHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onIdle(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemsCount) {
                //TODO: начать загрузку картинок
            }
        }, mRecyclerView));
```

Еще могу посоветовать использовать Glide вместо Picasso, он шустрее, судя по тестам.

Comment: `Glide` в списке не оптимизирован.

Answer (score 0):

У меня все реализовано через [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), правда надо немного попотеть, чтобы правильно масштабировать картинки перед выдачей, иначе можно напороться на `OutOfMemoryError`.

По сути `Universal-Image-Downloader` позволяет организовать отдельные потоки на каждую загрузку изображения, причем самыми разными способами: через `InputStream` или через `ContentProvider` или еще как то иначе. Можно настроить, чтобы в момент загрузки он показывал специальную пустышку или при ошибке загрузки другую заглушку-*stub*

Comment: Надо же, я думал что `UIL` это прошлый век :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить Picasso на Glide - по написанию кода фактически идентичны, однако последняя гораздо более производительнее при прочих равных.
И мне кажется что если у вас идет загрузка картинок которые вы прокручиваете - не повод ли это применить placeholder?
По поводу оптимизации RecyclerView - он и не грузит сразу все, он грузит то что на экране + 1 позиция сверху и снизу.

Comment: Glide в списке? Он не оптимизирован под них, где-то видел, что он не работал корректно, человек пересел на Picasso

Answer (score 0):

Знакомая проблема. Вам необходимо обрезать загруженную фотографию по размерам `ImageView`. Если вы этого делать не будете, то конечно все будет виснуть. Зачем держать на экране больше чем нужно?

```
imageView.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
    Picasso.with(context).
        load(url).
        resize(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight()).
        into(imageView);
}
}
```